# Bind AJAX success data to view page controls in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view page which contains two fields. I want to display the result of an AJAX request in the textboxes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployeeName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployeeName)                    
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployeeAge)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployeeAge)

    <input type="button" value="Load" id="btnLoad" />
}
```

This is my controller action method code:

```
public ActionResult UpdateName()
{
    EmmployeeModel obj = new EmmployeeModel();
    obj.EmployeeName = "Saty";
    obj.EmployeeAge = 20;
    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On click of the button this is my ajax method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnLoad").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateName")',
            success: function (result) {
                debugger
                $('#myForm').html(result);
            }
         });
    })
})
```

The output from the ajax success  looks like

```
{
    "EmployeeName": "Satya",
    "EmployeeAge": 20
}
```

How can I bind the model data to my respective controls in the form?

Comment: I assume `dataType: 'html',` is  typo - it needs to be `dataType: 'json',`. The value of `result` contains the data, so it would be `$('#EmployeeName'').val(result.EmployeeName);` (ditto for `EmployeeAge`)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Stephen.Sorry to mention.I know this approach.But i any clue to add all the values at one shot??